# Spyder internal problem , how do i fix it?

Tags: python, spyder

I am completely new to coding. However, when i try to run some code as shown, this problem shows up. I tried reinstalling but it doesn't work.

[image: Spyder error]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  I think the best thing to do is to contact the maintainer.

Comment: Please edit your post so that it doesn't contain [images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Sorry for the inconvenience. This is an error in Anaconda, which we already reported to them but it hasn't been fixed yet.

If you only need to use create Python programs, please consider to download and install our Windows installer, which you can find [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases) and doesn't have this problem.